# Exclude the lag at 0 from ACF/PACF plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series

I am wondering if there is a way to exclude the lag at 0 from ACF/PACF plot? Because people only interest in the positive lags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that, since anyone would expect the zero-lag coefficient to be there and would likely to read the plot incorrectly if you exclude it.

In any case, I don't see a neat way of doing it for *crosscorrelation*, since you output will not in general be symmetrical, and therefore you can't just omit something in the middle of the signal. However, if you're performing *autocorrelation*, and I believe that you are from what you wrote, you can only keep the *positive* lags, since you signal is symmetrical. Do to that, I'd write

```
%# Generate some signal
x = rand(1,10);

%# Compute its autocorrelation, whichever flavor you prefer
acf = xcorr(x);

%# Keep only the positive lags
acf = acf( length(x)+1 : end );

%# Plot your result
stem(acf);
```